# Draggable Icon Not Showing on top of the Google Map and not Duplicating

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dom-events

How can I implement draggable icons markers using this [Google Maps Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

So far I have the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Places search box</title>
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 93%;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px
    }
    #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1%;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    #target {
        width: 345px;
    }
    #shelf{position:absolute; top: 0px; left:980px; height:100%;width:30%; float: right; background:white;opacity:0.7;}
    #draggable {position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width: 30px; height: 30px;z-index:1000000000;}
    </style>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                stop: function(e) {
                    var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                    var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                    var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                    placeMarker(ll, icon);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $map;
        var $latlng;
        var overlay;
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the
        // Google Places autocomplete feature. People can enter geographical searches.
        // The search box will return a pick list containing
        // a mix of places and predicted search terms.
        function initialize() {
            var markers = [];
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(37.3333, -121.9000),
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.3333, -121.9000));
            map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('target');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

            // [START region_getplaces]
            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
            // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
            google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                marker.setMap(null);
                }

                // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
                markers = [];
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                    var image = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                // Create a marker for each place.
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
                // [END region_getplaces]

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
            // current map's viewport.
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                var bounds = map.getBounds();
                searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
            });
            overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
                overlay.draw = function() {};
                overlay.setMap($map);
        }
        function placeMarker(location, icon) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            icon: icon                                                    
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="shelf">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lightly-icons/30/location.png" id="draggable" title="Estation Trash/Compost" alt="Estation Trash and Compost"/>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you load up the code, you will notice that the icon can be dragged only once. Also, when I try to drag the icon ONTO the map, the icon is dragged BEHIND the map and can not be seen. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? I have a feeling this piece of code is part of the problem...

```
function placeMarker(location, icon) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            icon: icon                                                    
            });
        }
```

Let me know.

---

**NOTE:** Below is the map that works with a draggable icon, BUT I want to implement this same method onto the search map that I have above. Thus, I am trying to combine the draggable function from the map below onto the search map above that I got from the [Google Map Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Demo Map</title>
 <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        html { 
            height: 100% 
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
         #map_canvas {
            width: 70%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #shelf{position:absolute; top: 0px; left:980px; height:100%;width:30%; float: right; background:white;opacity:0.7;}
                    #draggable {position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width: 30px; height: 30px;z-index:1000000000;}           
    </style>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                stop: function(e) {
                    var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                    var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                    var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                    placeMarker(ll, icon);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $map;
        var $latlng;
        var overlay;
        function initialize() {
            var $latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.32758, -121.89246);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 19,
                center: $latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT },
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                },
                scaleControl: true,
                scaleControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                },
                streetViewControl: false,

                panControl:false,

            };
            $map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

            overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            overlay.draw = function() {};
            overlay.setMap($map);
        } 
        function placeMarker(location, icon) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location, 
                map: $map,
                draggable:true,
                icon: icon                                  
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id='shelf'>
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lightly-icons/30/location.png" id="draggable" title="Estation Trash/Compost" alt="Estation Trash and Compost"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm close but any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Why did you delete your original post?  The code you posted there works perfectly for me in Chrome once I add the Google Maps Javascript API to it.

Comment: @geocodezip The original post was very vague so I wanted to make one that was more detailed. Do you have any ideas on the issue I am having? The icon does not seem to be dragging properly. I'm sure i am just not connecting them correctly but can't pinpoint the cause of the problem

Comment: [this example by Wolfgang Pichler works](http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/drag-from-outside.html)

Comment: @geocodezip The link you provided is what i'm trying to accomplish and I have that working with the second block of code i provided. However, when i tried to connect that method to the search map i provided in the first block of code, it does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tricks to avoid dragging behind the map.  On the draggable item use these options:

```
helper: "clone",
appendTo: "body"
```

By appending to body, the cloned helper will be the newest item created, and will be on top of the map.